# Activity with dynamicly added components freezes

Tags: android, custom-component

My Application freezes and LogCat grows heap (frag case) to 14mb if add more then 3 own "components" to current activity/layout. It takes very long until the fourth "component" is added and Android asks to close my application.

I've written a Activity which has some components (EditTexts) and a own "component". I want to do something similar to the contacts app (Number adding) but with ingredients. So I've created a class IngredientsLayout which extends LinearLayout and a Layout xml file with a TextView and a "Add"-Button which I've placed on the Activity-Layout. Every time I press the Add Button, a single IngredientLayout with 3 EditTexts and a ImageButton will be added to the current IngredientsLayout which should "hold" all added ingredients.

What I'm doing wrong?

IngredientsLayout class:

```
public class IngredientsLayout extends LinearLayout {

ImageButton imageButtonAddIngredient;
ArrayList<IngredientLayout> arrayList;

public IngredientsLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.ingredients_list, this);

    arrayList = new ArrayList<IngredientLayout>();
    imageButtonAddIngredient = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonAddIngredient);
    imageButtonAddIngredient.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutIngredientsList);
            IngredientLayout ingredientLayout = new IngredientLayout(getContext(), null);
            ingredientLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  
            arrayList.add(ingredientLayout);
            layout.addView(ingredientLayout);
        }

    });
}
}
```

ingredients_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutIngredientsList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/ingredients_list_name" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonAddIngredient"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_add_ingredient" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

IngredientLayout class:

```
public class IngredientLayout extends LinearLayout {
public IngredientLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.ingredients_list_row, this);
}
}
```

ingredients_list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/linearLayoutIngredientRow"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editTextAmount"
      android:layout_width="45dp"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="0.11"
      android:ems="10"
      android:hint="@string/ingredients_list_listrow_amount"
      android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

      <requestFocus />
  </EditText>

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editTextUnit"
      android:layout_width="60dp"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="0.06"
      android:ems="10"
      android:hint="@string/ingredients_list_listrow_unit" /><EditText
      android:id="@+id/editTextName"
      android:layout_width="127dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="left"
      android:layout_weight="0.005"
      android:ems="10"
      android:hint="@string/ingredients_list_listrow_name" />

<ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_cancel" />

</LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayouts are not meant for this kind of dynamic accessing.
What you need to do is a ListView and a adapter.

And every time you add a new item into the adapter you call it's NottifyDataChanged to update the list view with the new item.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting a similar behavior :-/