# android listview with custom adapter freezes activity

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, custom-adapter

I want to do something similar to the EditContact activity (add various numbers to contact with a simple add button).

My first approach was to create custom layouts which I dynamically add to the activitie layout ( [Activity with dynamicly added components freezes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108943/activity-with-dynamicly-added-components-freezes) ) The user Budius mentioned to use listview with custom adapter to achieve a solution. So i tried it, but the behavior ends like my first try.

After adding 3-4 entries the activity freezes. (on a galaxy s3 and the emulator)

Maybe you have an idea?

Logcat:

```
11-01 15:42:33.214: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 148K, 3% free 8283K/8519K, paused 74ms+102ms, total 242ms
11-01 15:42:33.733: I/Choreographer(712): Skipped 93 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-01 15:42:42.293: I/Choreographer(712): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-01 15:42:44.946: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 72K, 2% free 8672K/8839K, paused 16ms+36ms, total 224ms
11-01 15:42:45.593: I/Choreographer(712): Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-01 15:42:48.913: I/Choreographer(712): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-01 15:42:49.093: I/Choreographer(712): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-01 15:42:55.083: I/Choreographer(712): Skipped 125 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-01 15:42:55.343: I/Choreographer(712): Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-01 15:42:55.653: I/Choreographer(712): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-01 15:43:02.553: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 318K, 5% free 8821K/9223K, paused 16ms+68ms, total 231ms
11-01 15:43:02.863: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 418K, 7% free 8800K/9415K, paused 73ms, total 76ms
11-01 15:43:02.883: I/Choreographer(712): Skipped 224 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-01 15:43:03.013: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 397K, 7% free 8804K/9415K, paused 74ms+6ms, total 113ms
11-01 15:43:03.013: D/dalvikvm(712): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 33ms
11-01 15:43:03.063: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 386K, 7% free 8802K/9415K, paused 41ms, total 41ms
11-01 15:43:03.183: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 388K, 7% free 8806K/9415K, paused 75ms+7ms, total 119ms
11-01 15:43:03.183: D/dalvikvm(712): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 35ms
11-01 15:43:03.243: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 378K, 7% free 8803K/9415K, paused 51ms, total 51ms
11-01 15:43:03.433: I/Choreographer(712): Skipped 142 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
comment:..... adding the 4. row to custom adapter and listview ..... 
11-01 15:36:31.662: I/Choreographer(712): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-01 15:36:32.542: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 23% free 9057K/11719K, paused 18ms+15ms, total 139ms
11-01 15:36:32.554: D/dalvikvm(712): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 123ms
11-01 15:36:32.613: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 492K, 23% free 9046K/11719K, paused 56ms, total 56ms
11-01 15:36:32.753: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 449K, 23% free 9078K/11719K, paused 76ms+7ms, total 134ms
11-01 15:36:32.753: D/dalvikvm(712): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 48ms
11-01 15:36:32.813: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 514K, 23% free 9046K/11719K, paused 54ms, total 54ms
11-01 15:36:32.943: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 451K, 23% free 9078K/11719K, paused 76ms+8ms, total 128ms
11-01 15:36:32.943: D/dalvikvm(712): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 44ms
11-01 15:36:33.013: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 516K, 23% free 9046K/11719K, paused 53ms, total 53ms
11-01 15:36:33.143: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 453K, 23% free 9078K/11719K, paused 75ms+9ms, total 127ms
11-01 15:36:33.143: D/dalvikvm(712): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 41ms
11-01 15:36:33.193: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 518K, 23% free 9046K/11719K, paused 50ms, total 50ms
11-01 15:36:33.333: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 454K, 23% free 9078K/11719K, paused 75ms+8ms, total 137ms
11-01 15:36:33.333: D/dalvikvm(712): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 59ms
11-01 15:36:33.393: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 520K, 23% free 9046K/11719K, paused 56ms, total 56ms
11-01 15:36:33.533: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 456K, 23% free 9079K/11719K, paused 75ms+8ms, total 129ms
11-01 15:36:33.533: D/dalvikvm(712): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 52ms
comment:..... many of this .....
11-01 15:40:05.064: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 451K, 23% free 9135K/11719K, paused 97ms, total 97ms
11-01 15:40:05.204: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 451K, 23% free 9135K/11719K, paused 76ms+6ms, total 136ms
11-01 15:40:05.204: D/dalvikvm(712): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 47ms
11-01 15:40:05.293: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 451K, 23% free 9135K/11719K, paused 66ms, total 66ms
11-01 15:40:05.443: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 451K, 23% free 9135K/11719K, paused 76ms+6ms, total 148ms
11-01 15:40:05.443: D/dalvikvm(712): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 67ms
11-01 15:40:05.513: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 451K, 23% free 9135K/11719K, paused 59ms, total 59ms
11-01 15:40:05.643: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 451K, 23% free 9135K/11719K, paused 76ms+7ms, total 127ms
11-01 15:40:05.643: D/dalvikvm(712): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 41ms
11-01 15:40:05.703: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 451K, 23% free 9135K/11719K, paused 56ms, total 56ms
11-01 15:40:05.833: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 451K, 23% free 9135K/11719K, paused 75ms+7ms, total 127ms
11-01 15:40:05.833: D/dalvikvm(712): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 42ms
11-01 15:40:05.913: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 451K, 23% free 9135K/11719K, paused 63ms, total 63ms
11-01 15:40:06.114: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 451K, 23% free 9135K/11719K, paused 76ms+39ms, total 196ms
11-01 15:40:06.114: D/dalvikvm(712): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 118ms
11-01 15:40:06.963: E/Trace(734): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-01 15:40:07.953: D/gralloc_goldfish(734): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

here is my activity:

```
package com.float.rezepte;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.float.utilities.ImageProcessing;
import com.float.utilities.Utilities;

public class AddRecipeActivity extends SherlockActivity {

private EditText editTextName;
private EditText editTextDescription;
private EditText editTextDuration;
private EditText editTextPortions;
private EditText editTextPortionsUnit;
private RatingBar ratingBarDifficutly;
private ImageView imageViewPicture;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 2;
public boolean deletePicture = false;
private String selectedImagePath;
private byte[] recipePicture = null;
private Recipe recipe;
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private IngredientAdapter ingredientAdapter;
private ImageButton imageButtonAddIngredient;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_recipe);
    ConnectView();
    ArrayList<Ingredient> values;

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        recipe = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("recipe");
        editTextName.setText(recipe.getName());
        editTextDescription.setText(recipe.getDescription());
        editTextDuration.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getDuration()));
        editTextPortions.setText(String.valueOf(recipe.getPortions()));
        editTextPortionsUnit.setText(recipe.getPortionsUnit());
        ratingBarDifficutly.setRating(recipe.getDifficulty());
        values = (ArrayList<Ingredient>) recipe.getIngredientList();
    }else{
        recipe = new Recipe();
        values = new ArrayList<Ingredient>();
    }

    ingredientAdapter = new IngredientAdapter(this, values); 
    final ListView listViewIngredients = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewIngredients);
    listViewIngredients.setAdapter(ingredientAdapter);

    imageButtonAddIngredient.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ingredientAdapter.addItem(new Ingredient());
            ingredientAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Utilities.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listViewIngredients);
        }
    });

    final ViewTreeObserver observer = imageViewPicture.getViewTreeObserver();
       observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener (new OnGlobalLayoutListener () {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {          
                imageViewPicture.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                if(recipe.getPicture() != null){
                    imageViewPicture.setImageBitmap(ImageProcessing.scaleImage(recipe.getPicture(), imageViewPicture.getWidth(), imageViewPicture.getHeight()));
                }
            }
        });
}

private void ConnectView(){
    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    editTextDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDescription);
    editTextDuration = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDuration);
    editTextPortions = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPortions);
    editTextPortionsUnit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPortionsUnit);
    ratingBarDifficutly = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBarDifficulty);
    imageViewPicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPicture);
    imageButtonAddIngredient = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonAddIngredient);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  savedInstanceState.putParcelable("recipe", copyUserInputToRecipe());
}

private Recipe copyUserInputToRecipe(){
    recipe.setName(editTextName.getText().toString());
    recipe.setDescription(editTextDescription.getText().toString());
    recipe.setDifficulty(ratingBarDifficutly.getRating());
    if(!editTextDuration.getText().toString().equals("")){
        recipe.setDuration(Integer.parseInt(editTextDuration.getText().toString()));
    }
    if(!editTextPortions.getText().toString().equals("")){
        recipe.setPortions(Integer.parseInt(editTextPortions.getText().toString()));
    }
    recipe.setPortionsUnit(editTextPortionsUnit.getText().toString());
    if(recipePicture != null){
        recipe.setPicture(recipePicture);
    }
    return recipe;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_add_recipe, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in,
            android.R.anim.fade_out);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_cancel_recipe:
        finish();
        break;
    case R.id.menu_save_recipe:
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("recipe", recipe);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();

        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

EDIT:
The ViewTreeObserver is the problem. After removing it, no freezes came up.

Comment: can you provide "some" logcat? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you store the image bytes to reuse when device orientation changes...

You can detect device orientation changes by overriding

```
    onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
```

method in your activity. Read on 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)

and

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html

Make sure to specify

```
    android:configChanges="orientation"
```

in the manifest entry for that activity. With this you can detect if the device is in portrait or landscape orientation. Most importantly this will only be triggered when the device orientation is changed (unlike the global layout listener which fires up with every slight change on the screen).

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. your implementation of addItem method in your adapter is not thread save. Make it synchronised. You also have a data.remove(...) call in your getView method - again done in a thread-unsafe way.
2. You modify your Ingredient object when the corresponding text is changed. In the implementation of your Ingredient class do you also change the content of the associated EditText component? If so, you'll enter into an infinite loop with your TextWatcher being invoked each time the editText.setText(...) is called. SGS 3 is a quad core CPU device so it can real-time process up to 4 threads (one is for the UI permanently, so leaves the other 3).

Address these points and see if you can catch the tail of the situation. The operation heaviness should not be much of a deal for SGS 3 - it has enough juice to cope.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why do you think it has to be thread-safe? I thought making something synchronized is only need when you work thread based. The ingredient class does nothing but holding variables (long, strings and integers). I added it to the main question.

Comment: The app behave the same, even if I remove the TextChangedListeners.

Comment: getView calls data.remove(...); - it will always be done from the UI thread. The data.add(...) happens in an API method which can be called from any Thread. So potentially there could be a concurrency issue. The point 2 for you should be ok, I looked into your class Ingredient, it does not have back-looping calls.

Comment: I've updated my adapter class with a remoteItem method and implemented this in the getView method. I've updated my post. But this doesn't fix my freeze issue when I'm adding more then 3-4 items.

Comment: I have some more code in my activity. Unfortunately I thought it doesn't matter, so I excluded it here. I found out that the OnGlobalLayoutListener I'm using causes this behaviour. I'll update my post. Do you have an Idea how I could modify this to fix it? Uncommenting isn't really what I want.

Comment: First off, you add the same global layout listener to the same observer twice. You don't need    imageViewPicture.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);    Secondly, I believe that you shouldn't be needing global Layout listener at all. You scale a picture in it manually. Can you detail a bit more what's the purpose of the scaling and when it is expected to get triggered? I believe there is much easier way to accomplish the same thing. As the name suggests the listener is global, so a slightest change in the view hierarchy, even a slight scroll, will invoke it.

Comment: I save a picture to sql data with 640x800 pixels. In future I have different Layouts for portrait and landscape (bigger imageView), I resize the stored picture to the real needed size to save memory. But I don't believe this functionality is needed in the "add"-actvity. But I use it also in the "show"-activity.

Comment: Ok I see, I'll make a new answer section for this.

Answer (score 0):

If i had to guess, it's seems like you have your text-watcher class inside of your adapter method, and more importantly the text listeners in `getView()`. So, I'm assuming that it's making the class for each row and listening for **each** row all at the same time, all the time. depending on how many rows you have, it might take alot of resources if text-watchers inherently do. You should find a way to implement it differently. perhaps do a set up outside of your adapter (to be safe), or some constructor work, or make the adapter implement it somehow. or what i'd do - only listen for the views in the selected row. and turn off when unselected. worth a shot.

**EDIT:** there are plenty of ways. but I think the simplest for `BaseAdapter` is to set a tag of  `position` on each of the things you want listened for and then `onFocusChanged` I suppose (if `OnClick` gave issues),  perform your action if the tag matches the position. But again all this might be unnecessary if it performs well without this. For all we know, the listener methods are already well optimized. It's just that I couldn’t think of another explanation at the time.

Comment: I removed the text-watcher class and listeners. But it's the same behavior. Any way, your suggestion sounds better then my approach. How could I implement your suggestion (adding and removing listeners to selected row)?

Comment: i gotta be honest, i was just taking a guess. I wasn't 100% on the answer. what @Nar Gar said seemed to make alot of sense though -- an infinite loop with the textwatcher and text changed. i think you should heed that advice, but if you want my implementation, I editted my post.

Answer (score 0):

If you do updates in the main ui or do them by thread or give network policy permission on main ui thread these things happen.

the only way to do this is using AsyncTask. get your data by this and at the end of asynctask set adapter view etc..